# Linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that any linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is a composition of scalings and shears?

Comment: Not true for projections...

Comment: $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,0)$ is a scaling and a projection, too.

Comment: how is shear defined for a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, the [$LDU$ decomposition of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)
of a transformation $T$ is a composition of a "$xy$-shear" $U$, a scaling $D$, and a "$yz$-shear" $L$.

Comment: so, what is the answer?

Comment: *Ahem:* "Yes".${}$

Comment: To answer your question to Bogdan: see the generalization given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping#General_shear_mappings).